# ExoMedia / Exoplayer MP3 metadata extractor

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Hiya I'm trying to make a simple radio application with the following stream: http://lb.topradio.be/topradio.mp3.

Currently I'm using ExoMedia for convenience as my default audioplayer.
It has this `setMetadataListener` method which never gets called because in the `Mp3Extractor` class the `peekId3Data` method has this check.

```
if (scratch.readUnsignedInt24() != Id3Decoder.ID3_TAG) {
    // Not an ID3 tag.
    break;
}
```

However when I throw the same stream in VLC Media Player it is able to successfully fetch the metadata from the stream.
How does this work?
Can I replicate this with a custom `Extractor` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue opened on the [Exoplayer repository](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2293). Basically the metadata is transferred through headers, not in the stream itself.

I had a success with the [audiostream-metadata-retriever](https://github.com/vsmaks/audiostream-metadata-retriever) although I had some track synchronization problems because of the stream caching and metadata arriving before the actual song starts playing.

**Edit:**

RxJava implementation:

```
private long icyMetaInt = 1000;

public void showStreamData() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Show stream metadata");
    streamService.getStreamData()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .repeatWhen(delays -> delays.concatMap(metaIntDelay -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "icyMetaDelay = " + icyMetaInt + "ms ");
                return Observable.timer(icyMetaInt, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }))
            .subscribe(new Observer<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "OnSubscribe");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onNext - " + response);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        InputStream stream = response.body().byteStream();
                        if (stream != null) {
                            icyMetaInt = Integer.parseInt(response.headers().get("icy-metaint"));
                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            try {
                                long skipped = stream.skip(icyMetaInt);
                                while (skipped != icyMetaInt) {
                                    skipped += stream.skip(icyMetaInt - skipped);
                                }

                                int symbolLength = stream.read();
                                int metaDataLength = symbolLength * 16;
                                if (metaDataLength > 0) {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < metaDataLength; ++i) {
                                        int metaDataSymbol = stream.read();
                                        if (metaDataSymbol > 0) {
                                            baos.write(metaDataSymbol);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    String result = baos.toString()
                                            .replace("StreamTitle=", "")
                                            .replaceAll("'", "")
                                            .replaceAll(";", "");
                                    baos.reset();

                                    Log.d(TAG, result);
                                    runOnUiThread(() -> textView.setText(result));

                                    Log.d(TAG, response.headers().get("ice-audio-info"));
                                    Log.d(TAG, response.headers().get("icy-description"));
                                    Log.d(TAG, response.headers().get("icy-genre"));
                                    Log.d(TAG, response.headers().get("icy-name"));
                                    Log.d(TAG, response.headers().get("icy-url"));
                                }

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                onError(e);
                                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to obtain metadata");
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    baos.close();
                                    stream.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    onError(e);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onError");
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete");
                }
            });
}
```

Retrofit interface:

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.Streaming;

public interface StreamService {

    @GET("stream")
    @Headers("Icy-MetaData:1")
    @Streaming
    Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> getStreamData();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Goran.
Your link for the issue tracker is broken I think.
However you put me on the right track for this. I used this library as an inspiration to fetch the metadata using Retrofit and Rx a bit cleaner imho.

Comment: You are right, I corrected the link. I agree that the library is a bit overkill and the simple response fetching would be enough. Will try it by myself when I have time. Please accept the answer.